# Is it possible to add Product Version to an existing exe file using Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, exe

I have generated `.res` file from `.rc` file using windows rc generator.
But I don't see any Microsoft or Visual Studio Commands to add Product Version Details to an available `.exe` file.

Is there any way to add Product Version details to `.exe` file using microsoft or visual studio commands?

note: I don't prefer using third party tools

Comment: Why the `python` tag?

Comment: Add the version info block to your resource file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource

Comment: @joshpoley  This is an Pyinstaller generated exe, i don't want to use pyinstaller for adding versions. instead i need to use microsoft or visual studio commands.

Comment: Add a "version resource" to the project's resources

Comment: no Dave it wont work

Comment: this is a python generated exe

Comment: Edit your question and tag to add pyinstaller?  If you have no .rc file the normal answers don't apply.  Your actual problem seems to be: How do I add a version resource to a pyinstaller exe, there might be pyinstaller answerrs.  (I can't say, I don't use python.)

Comment: @DaveS i dont want to use pyinstaller, need to use only visual studio commands or any microsoft tools commands.

Comment: Is this EXE created by someone else? Normally people are not adding versions to other people's EXEs which is why we're giving suggestions that assume you are the one building the EXE.